# media Queries conflict

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to make my site responsive on 2 devices

1. Samsung tab (600 x 1024)
2. iPad (768 x 1024)

using below media queries

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 600px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait){  }
```

and

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait){  }
```

but while I am opening my site on Samsung Tab its applying iPad's media queries style

what can I do for this?

Comment: Use: https://github.com/tarunsharma20/initiator

Comment: Using media queries to target specific devices is a horrible way to do RWD (see:  http://designshack.net/articles/css/responsive-design-why-youre-doing-it-wrong/ and http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to avoid overlap in your media queries.  Don't think of it in terms of which device, but which screen size.  Target 600-767 pixels in one, and 768-1024 in another, like so:

**Samsung Tab in portrait**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 600px) and (max-device-width : 767px)
```

**Samsung Tab in landscape and iPad in either**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)
```